# Strange ASP.NET error !

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-ajax

I'm running Windows 7 - x64 Edition with IIS 7.5

I have a simple asp.net website that i've run on other versions of windows and IIS but now, on SOME pages it gives me the following error

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpParseException 
    Exception message: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
......

Now, when i run this application under cassini everything works fine. I also was able to figure out that where ever i have used the AjaxToolkit controls those pages are throwing this error.

Any advice ?

Comment: Could this be a UAC issue?  Try turning that off and see if this improves any...

Comment: Can you show some code of the function that throws this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In IIS, Under the advanced settings. You must try to set

> Load User Profile=True

see this link for more detail [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200803211949/http://geekswithblogs.net/ProjectLawson/archive/2009/05/05/iis-system.web.aspnethostingpermission-exception-on-windows-7-rc.aspx)

Comment: One day I will learn.  Check stackoverflow first!  Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Or try the answers in here. http://forums.asp.net/t/1116931.aspx?Ajax+Request+for+the+permission+of+type+System+Web+AspNetHostingPermission+System The reply from @Pepepe was the only solution that worked for me.