# What exactly happens when I set LoadUserProfile of IIS pool?

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, x509certificate, application-pool

I faced the following issue.

I run the following code

```
var binaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToPfxFile);
var cert = new X509Certificate2(binaryData, password);
```

in two processes. One of the processes runs under `LOCAL_SYSTEM` and there this code succeeds. Another one runs inside IIS under a local user account belonging to "Users" local group and there I get the following exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
Object was not found.
at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password)
//my code here
```

So I Googled a bit and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10048789/57428) to a kind of similar question. I tried to enable `LoadUserProfile` for the application pool and it works now.

The problem is I don't get what exactly happens when I set `LoadUserProfile` and what consequences that might have. I mean if it's a "good" thing then why it is not "on" by default and why is it there after all?

What exactly happens when I set `LoadUserProfile` in IIS pool and what negative consequences can it have?

Comment: Just an afterthought, if loading the user profile is a problem for you, you can change your loading of the certificate to `new X509Certificate2(binaryData, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)` so a user profile isn't needed.

Comment: If running as ApplicationPoolIdentity, you will want to use `new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, keyFilePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.EphemeralKeySet)` which avoids writing the private key to the store and wont require administrative privileges on the server.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

> I mean if it's a "good" thing then why it is not "on" by default and why is it there after all?

IIS 6 never loaded user profiles. I would assume this is off by default to keep the behavior consistent, and an administrator has to opt-in to it.

> I tried to enable LoadUserProfile for the application pool and it works now.

This is most likely because the Windows Cryptographic Service Provider was trying to store or load a key for your certificate in the user store, and since a profile was not available, a [cryptographic context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_security_key_container_gly) was not available. Note that the `Load User Profile` setting only applies to user accounts. Service Accounts like NETWORK SERVICE and ApplicationPoolIdentity have special handling.

> What exactly happens when I set LoadUserProfile in IIS pool

Well, the user profile is loaded. This includes their cryptographic store, environment variables such as %TEMP%, and other ones.

What it eventually boils down to is [`LoadUserProfile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is called by IIS when the AppPool starts.

> what negative consequences can it have?

It may break backwards compatibility with an app that ran on IIS 6, which didn't load the user profile. The environment variables are loaded. For example, when Load User Profile is true, the %TEMP% environment variable is `C:\Users\AccountName\AppData\Local\Temp` (for example). When false, it's `C:\WINDOWS\Temp`.

Comment: +1 For NETWORK SERVICE as app pool identity, but ApplicationPoolIdentity wasn't successful for me.

Comment: "It may break backwards compatibility with an app that ran on IIS 6, which didn't load the user profile." I would guess it also has performance (the profile has to actually be loaded; this means, for instance, loading the HKCU registry hive) and security (bigger potential vector) implications.

Comment: Is it possible to set `LoadUserProfile=true` in IIS and change the default temp folder %TEMP% location from `C:\Users\C:\Users\AccountName\AppData\Local\Temp` to somewhere else? example "D:\AppTempData"

Comment: Murali Murugesan - did you ever get an answer to this question? I have the same issue. I want the default Temp directory changed.

Comment: I ran into this years ago building a back-end service that called into a remote web service protected by X509 Client Certificate authentication. Because personal certificates are stored in a user's profile, when installing the service, I had to log on to the target server as the service's logon account, which creates a user profile, then install the client certificate into the logon account's certificate store. After that, the client certificate would load at run time.

Comment: What if that just a service account, you cannot logon to machine using service account

Comment: @VBAHole you can set a TMP/TEMP environment variable in the users' registry @ HKEY_USERS\SID\Environment. Substitute SID with the security identifier of the user in question.