# CrystalReport "Load report failed" error only for some users

Tags: asp.net, iis, crystal-reports

I have encountered the `Load report failed` error when generating report by IIS with CrystalReport.

**Error occurs only for some users but not others.**

Therefore I suspect that it is due to permissions. I have checked:

1. Both users can access the folder containing the rpt files.
2. IIS_IUSRS has permission to access the %TEMP% folder.

Where else should I check?

Error Message:

> Load report failed.
>
> at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
>   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
>   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
>   ...

Comment: You might check which version of software is being used to view the report. (We use Report Viewer and *many* problems are solved by standardizing the version we use.)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue by setting the IIS `Application Pool -> Advanced Settings -> Load User Profile` to **False**. (Default is **True**)

When `Load User Profile` is True, environment variables such as %TEMP% will be changed.

[What exactly happens when I set LoadUserProfile of IIS pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149132/what-exactly-happens-when-i-set-loaduserprofile-of-iis-pool)