# Parse Bytes[] as X509Certificate in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, certificate

I created a web service that receives a .p12 file as a Byte Array and parses it as X509Certificate, when I tested it locally it worked just fine, but when I deployed it I'm getting the following error when trying to create the X509Certificate:

> The system cannot find the file specified.

The code

```
//cerBytes is a Byte[] and passCert is a String
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, passCert);
```

As I read, the problem is that it's trying to read the Certificate from the actual server, which is not the behaviour I'm looking for, I just need to parse the certificate from the Byte Array (that come from different senders/customers) sign an XML and that's it, There's no need to store the Certificate in the server.

Is there anyway to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: Can you let us see your web service code and how do you convert the received file into a byte array.

Comment: Rani, that’s the actual Code, the X509Certificate constructor accepts the byte array and the password of the p12 file. It also has another one when instead of the byte array receives a file path, but since this is executed via web service. The path will never be valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly happens when I set LoadUserProfile of IIS pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149132/what-exactly-happens-when-i-set-loaduserprofile-of-iis-pool)

Comment: Thanks Rene, the thing is that the hosting that I’m using won’t let me configure stuff on IIS, everything is deployed as a web application (gear host)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on [BinaryFormatter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx)
, on client side, create the X509Certificate2 object, once serialized and sent, create a new MemoryStream with given byte array and deserialize it as X509Certificate2 on server side, hope this helps :)