# Import method of windows security encryption algorithm is not working in hosting environment

Tags: asp.net-core, cryptography, rsa

I need to use RSA cryptography for encryption of data. I have used **ImportPkcs8PrivateKey** method of System.Security.Cryptography for importing private key. The code working fine in visual studio but only **ImportPkcs8PrivateKey** method is not working in hosting server. My Hosting server is windows 2019 and I have installed all hosting package.

```
var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(marchentPrivateKey);
int myarray;
var rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(privateKeyBytes, out myarray);
return rsa;
```

The following Error trace is generated in hosted server

```
 at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

Comment: What does *...is not working in hosting server...* mean? Which .NET version is running on the server?

Comment: @Topaco I am using .net core 3.1 and i have installed all from this link into server https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1     , in visual studio no exception but in hosting server it didn't found ImportPkcs8PrivateKey method

Comment: [`ImportPkcs8PrivateKey()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importpkcs8privatekey?view=netcore-3.1) is supported since .NET Core 3.0. So if you are really running .NET Core 3.1, then there is something wrong with your installation.

Comment: @Topaco I have updated the post with the error trace generating in server when calling import method

Answer (score 0):

Actually its issue of IIS setting. Cryptographic Service Provider try to store  a key for certificate in the user store and if a profile was not available, a cryptographic context was not available. By default IIS Load User Profile is false. See for more details
[What exactly happens when I set LoadUserProfile of IIS pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149132/what-exactly-happens-when-i-set-loaduserprofile-of-iis-pool)