# Calling Rest endpoint throws "Could not create ssl/tls secure channel" on Windows Server 2019 with .NET 4.8

Tags: rest, ssl, tls1.2

I am making a REST call to a https endpoint in .NET 4.8. The endpoint is requiring a client certificate (pfx) as well and supports Tls 1.1 and Tls 1.2.

On application startup i'm setting once this:

```
try
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls |
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
    log.Warn( "TLS 1.3 as security protocol type is not usable on this machine. Using TLS 1.2 instead.", ex );
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
}
```

We have a lot of different external API calls but the rudimentary code of the endpoint that fails is:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add( new X509Certificate2( path, password ) );

HttpClient client = new HttpClient( handler );
// Set url and basic authentication...
client.GetAsync(resource);
```

The certificates are valid and stored in the right place in certmgr.

The request works on my local development machine (Win10).

It throws "Could not create ssl/tls secure channel" exception on a Windows Server 2019.

I tried setting handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls11 resp. Tls12 but the error keeps the same.

Tls 1.2 should be enabled by default on Win Server 2019. How can I check if it is enabled?

Does anyone have another idea here?

Thank you!

Comment: This fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149132/what-exactly-happens-when-i-set-loaduserprofile-of-iis-pool